# Trigger a macro when a new named range is created?

Tags: vba, excel

Basically I am trying to list all the named ranges in the workbook somewhere. But I just want this to happen when a new name is created or when an existing named range is deleted. Any way I can capture this event. Or somehow trigger the macro only when this happens?

Comment: Backing up a bit, why are named ranges being created/deleted so frequently?  They're intended to be somewhat permanent, hence the name.

Comment: Well, they are not created frequently. Hence I want to capture that event and not assign that macro to sheet_change or something like that. It's basically for a user interface and I want the list of names objects to be updated only when a new range is named

Comment: X-Y problem: make your user interface pull the names once, add a "refresh" button, ...or use the names manager? There's no such event..

Comment: `the list of names objects to be updated only when a new range is named` - this range always has the same name right?  You can just change the range instead of deleting and recreating it.

Comment: (or better yet, do what @MathieuGuindon suggested)

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I think the Refresh button would be the best option if such an event is not there.

Comment: Automatic trigger would be something like `Workbook_Change` or `WorkSheet_Change`. Probably you could implement your code there handle the events in an If-Statement. Unfortunately this code would be called, whenever you change ANYTHING. So it slows down your file/workbook.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably the closest you can get to capturing the "change named range event". It will detect a named range change each time a selection change is made in the sheet, but it will not detect the change if you simply make it in the Name Manager under Formulas.

1) 
Insert this in the **This workbook module**:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Call updateNamedRangesVar
End Sub
```

2) Insert this in the **worksheet module** in which you wish to detect named range changes. (If necessary, insert in all worksheet modules):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Call detectNamedRangeChange
End Sub
```

3) Finally, insert this in a **regular module**:

```
    Option Explicit

    Public pubNamedRanges As Variant

Sub updateNamedRangesVar()

    Dim i As Integer, namCount As Integer
    namCount = ThisWorkbook.Names.count

    If Not IsEmpty(pubNamedRanges) Then Erase pubNamedRanges

    If namCount > 0 Then
        ' take snapshot of named ranges
        ReDim pubNamedRanges(1 To namCount) As Variant
        For i = 1 To namCount
            pubNamedRanges(i) = ThisWorkbook.Names(i)
        Next i
    End If
End Sub

Sub detectNamedRangeChange()

    Dim changeBool As Boolean
    Dim i As Integer, namRngCount As Integer, namRngCountNew As Integer

    On Error Resume Next
    namRngCount = UBound(pubNamedRanges)
    On Error GoTo 0
    namRngCountNew = ThisWorkbook.Names.count

    If namRngCount <> namRngCountNew Then
        MsgBox "Change of number of named ranges from" & vbNewLine & _
            namRngCount & " to " & namRngCountNew
        changeBool = True
    Else
        If namRngCountNew > 0 Then
            With ThisWorkbook
            For i = 1 To namRngCountNew
                If CStr(.Names(i)) <> CStr(pubNamedRanges(i)) Then
                    MsgBox "Named range changed from " & vbNewLine & _
                        pubNamedRanges(i) & vbNewLine & " to " & vbNewLine & _
                        .Names(i)
                    changeBool = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next i
            End With
        Else
            MsgBox "Number of named ranges is now zero"
            changeBool = True
        End If
    End If

    If changeBool Then Call updateNamedRangesVar

End Sub
```

Notice the public variable which must be declared outside the scope of the subs.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function:

```
Public NameCount As Long 'public 
Function CountNames(vola As Boolean) As Long
    Application.Volatile vola
    If NameCount <> ThisWorkbook.Names.Count Then
    MsgBox "start your macro here"
    NameCount = ThisWorkbook.Names.Count
    End If
    CountNames = NameCount
End Function
```

add somewhere in a cell in your workbook: =CountNames(TRUE)
Make sure calculation is set to xlAutomatic